# Loop through Worksheets with similar name structure in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My Excel file has the following structure of Worksheets:

`A1` `A2` `A3` `A4` `B1` `B2` `B3` `C1` `C2` `C3` `C4` `C5` ...

So as you can see 4 times A, 3 times B, 5 times C etc (no even distribution)

What I would like to do is loop through groups of worksheets and apply some code. In this case it must be the same code within groups but different code between groups, therefore I cannot simply loop through all worksheets at the same time.

I know how to get the names of the Worksheets in VBA. My first idea was to first 'cut off' the numbers (last character) from the right of the groupnames and then to identify unique groups of the results. Then I wanted to loop for each group, e.g. the first loop would start in A1 and stop at A4. But how can I tell VBA to identify an upper boundary in name that is not constant (in the example A4, then B3, then C5 etc.)?

Maybe that is not the most efficient way either. I could even rename all my worksheets to a different system if that would make any sense, but coding has to be applied in any case. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

What I want to do, in short:

1) Identify unique groups of Worksheeps by name (A, B, C in the example above)

2) For each group, loop through all associated sheets and apply some code

Thanks.

Comment: just write a small method that returns a boolean value and check to see if the worksheet exists, if it does then return true and do your work, if not then you reached the end of the range and move to the next set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way.. if your names are just A - Z

```
Sub DoStuff()
Dim i As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
'loop through A to Z
For i = 65 To 90
    counter = 1
   'loop until we no longer have a valid sheet
    Do While isWorksheet(Chr(i) + CStr(counter)) = True
        'do work by calling the correct method
        Run (setSubName(Chr(i)))
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
Next i
End Sub

'check to see if the worksheet exists
Function isWorksheet(name As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo wsError
Err.Clear
'just try and access the name
Sheets(name).name

wsError:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        isWorksheet = True
    Else
        isWorksheet = False
    End If
End Function


'set the sub routine name to call
Function setSubName(value As String) As String
    setSubName = Switch(value = "A", "Sub_A_Name", value = "B", "Sub_B_Name", _
    value = "C", "Sub_C_Name", value = "D", "Sub_D_Name")
End Function


Sub Sub_A_Name()
    'do work for group A
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I like the use of `Chr` in the loop particularly because it allows to easily loop from A to Z.

Comment: edit: Unfortunately I get an error 438 when I run your code, the problem seems to be the line `Sheets(name).name`. The `Err.Number` is always set to 438 and `isWorksheet` is always set to false (I noticed in Debug mode). What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: what is the name that is passed in and is it a valid sheet name?  The code does work as I have tested so the issue is with the Sheet name you are passing in.

Answer (score 3):

For identifying unique groups, you could do a loop that looks at the worksheet name, and if it has an "A", do X, "B", do Y, etc.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

For each ws in Activebook.Sheets
    If ws.name like "A*" Then
       ** Code for "A" worksheets
    Else If ws.name like "B" Then
       ** code for "B*" worksheets
    Else If [...]
    End if

Next ws
```

You could then create other macros for each sheet type and call that in the above code.  i.e.:

```
Private Sub A_Things()
  msgbox("This is a sheet 'A' type")
  [...whatever other code you want]
End Sub

Private Sub B_Things()
 msgbox("This is a sheet 'B' type")
 [...whatever other code you want]
End Sub

Sub checkSheets()

    Dim ws as Worksheet

    For each ws in Activebook.Sheets
        If ws.name like "A*" Then
           Call A_Things
        Else If ws.name like "B" Then
           Call B_Things
        Else If [...]
        End if
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Edit: For the part regarding only wanting to do this on certain sheets, or setting some upper boundary...If you know exactly what sheets you want to run the code on, you could instead put them into an Array, then run the code only on sheets in that array.

Something like (psuedocode):

```
Dim nameArray() as Variant
ReDim nameArray(4) 'Note, this can hold 5 values, so if you have X sheets, ReDim this to X-1 sheets

nameArray = Array("A1","A2","A4","B1","B3")

for i = 0 to UBound(nameArray())
  'this will loop through Sheet A1, then A2, then A4, etc. and run the code below
    If nameArray(i) = "A1" Then
         [run A1 code]
    ElseIf [...]
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This solution is nice as well. I'd accept both if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [Dictionary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234) to define groups and count of sheet in each group.

Here is an idea:

```
Sub LoopThroughGroupsOfSheets()
'Needs reference to MS Scripting Runtime
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim wshName As String

'define Sheets for loop and count of them
Set dic = New Dictionary
dic.Add "A", 4
dic.Add "B", 3
dic.Add "C", 5

For k = 0 To dic.Count - 1
    For i = 1 To dic.Items(k)
        DoSomething  dic.Keys(k) & i
    Next
Next

End Sub

Sub DoSomething(wshName As String)

    Debug.Print wshName

End Sub
```

Result:

```
SheetName: A1
SheetName: A2
SheetName: A3
SheetName: A4
SheetName: B1
SheetName: B2
SheetName: B3
SheetName: C1
SheetName: C2
SheetName: C3
SheetName: C4
SheetName: C5
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good solution, despite that one has to count manually the number of sheets below the line `Set dic = New Dictionary`

Comment: Thank you. As far i understand that the collection of sheets (groups) is defined, so... Cheers, Maciej